# Which of the two following solutions is correct for absolute value of this expression?

Tags: real-analysis, absolute-value

I'm currently going through Spivak and ran across this problem, but i see a difference in my answer and the answer that i'm checking it again.

The problem is to eliminate the absolute value signs in $|(|x|-1)|$

In my approach, i take two cases: $|x| < 1$ or $|x| \ge 1$

Evaluating the first case we get $-(x-1)$ and evaluating the second we get $x-1$.

In the answer that i'm comparing it against however,

> |(|x|-1)| This becomes |x|-1 and 1-|x|.
>
> |x|-1 can be either x-1 or -x-1.
>
> 1-|x| can be either 1-x or x+1.
>
> Four possibilities.

I don't see why we should evaluate the outer absolute block first

Comment: When you are doing your first case you will get $-(|x|-1)$ and not $-(x-1)$. Likewise you should change your second case answer as well.

Comment: Have you graphed $\left| |x| - 1 \right|$?  I get a "W" -- four parts.

Comment: Why? The fact that x < 1 would mean (x-1) is negative. This would justify multiplying it with -1 to make it positive

Comment: There is a difference between saying $x<1$ and $|x|<1$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'eliminate the absolute value signs'?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$||x|-1|=
\begin{cases}
|x|-1 & \text{if } |x| \geq 1\\
-(|x|-1) & \text{if } |x| < 1.
\end{cases}
$$
Now do two cases, namely $x \geq 0$ and $x <0$ for each part of the 
piecewise function.